# Best approach for drawing a graph of almost infinite size in a UIScrollView on iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm currently working on an app which needs to draw s.th. like a network graph. Unfortunately this graph can become very big with thousands of movable objects.

I tried to put a giant UIView inside a UIScrollView but soon noticed this won't work because of memory limitations.
So I tried another approach: currently I have a UIView which has exactly the size of the visible part of the UIScrollView. The scrollview is set to not handle the scrolling (only the pinching). Instead I handle the scrolling in the UIView. Everytime a user scrolls, all graphic objects (those graphic objects are currently just subclasses of NSObject, which contain custom drawing code) are moved, so it seems like the view is scrolling. In the drawRect I only draw the graphics that are currently visible.
Also I constantly add and remove sublayers if they are moved out/in the visible frame
This works very smooth even with thousands of objects.

Unfortunately this approach has some drawbacks:

- I can't zoom out to see all the objects in the graph, instead the user can only see a part of it
- I don't get the inertial scrolling the UIScrollView offers

Other approaches I tried, like the CATiledLayer, don't work either because all the objects in the graph are draggable by the user and it looks really ugly if I use a CATiledLayer...
Swapping out the UIView with other UIViews while the user scrolls may help with the inertial scrolling, but it makes everything more complicated and zooming out completely still won't work :-(

Do you know of any best practices to draw graphs that can be very big?

//edit: I ended up with a uiscrollview which has a subview which has a cascrolllayer which has many sublayers. While zooming in and out the frame of the uiscrollviews subview is constantly changed to the uiscrollviews bounds by view.frame = scrollview.bounds. While dragging the scrollview the cascrolllayer is always forced to scroll to the current offset of the scrollview.
 I needed to subclass the uiscrollview and hack around in order to make the zooming work nicely, but it's working well now. This approach works very well and allows very big graphs with lots of draggable elements.

//edit: see my other answer below, the approach above didn't work out as well as I initially thought, especially the zooming part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CATiledLayer is definitely what you should use here—there’s not really another solution that’ll let you use Quartz/UIKit drawing on a huge zoomable canvas. For anything that needs to be interactive (dragged or animated or whatever), you can disable its display in the main tiled layer and overlay another view or layer on top of it that just contains the object being interacted with.

Comment: unfortunately I think this won't work. The problem I ran into is that the overlay view would have to be exactly the same size as the main view and also have the same scaling etc. in order to display the graphics at the same size and position as in the main view...  I have no idea how to handle this :-(

Comment: hey, after a lot of experiments CATiledLayer proved to be the best solution. But the thing you need to know: don't draw in the tiled layer directly, add sublayers to the tiledlayer and draw only them. Also if you zoom only change the scale of those sublayers. Working very smooth now.